# How to pass data between the contentscript and background.html in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am passing the data from content script to background.html in the below code but it doesn't works for me due to some reason..Here is the code..

Contentscript.js

```
    var a1 ="Shan";
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({method:"text",txt:a1}, function(response) {
      d=response.data;
      alert(d);
    });
```

background.html

```
   if(request.method == "text")
   {
       sendResponse({data:request.key});
   } 
   else
   {
     sendResponse({data:request.key});
   }
```

My question is why I am not able to pass the variable "a1" to background.html?? Whether it can't be done?

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html The code you posted does not seem to be complete. If this is all you have I suggest to have a look at the documentation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the key is named `txt`, not `key`.

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method:"text",txt:a1}
                                            ^^^ Your definition: txt

 sendResponse({data:request.key});
                            ^^^ Should be txt as well
```

Warning: I've experienced that you cannot recycle the `sendResponse` method. After firing `sendResponse`, the extension will not responde to future `sendResponse` calls.
So, only one `sendResponse` for each `chrome.extension.sendRequest`.

Comment: I have tested with key too but it just doesn't works..why it is?

Comment: @Shan You have to be consistent. Use `txt` OR `key`. After updating the code, reload your extension to see the effect.

Comment: The problem is the variable a1 is not getting passed to background.html..whereas if you give something like in quotes "work" it's getting passed to background.html..

Comment: That's impossible. Can you post your code in the question, or at http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: @Shan I have just tested your code, and it works. Did you **really** reload the extension?